# My Selenium app sends files to php input two times

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've php interface to send files to sftp server and there is written simple input form:

```
<div class="doc">
  <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div>
  <h2>Upload files</h2>
  <input type="file" name="f" multiple=""/>
  <input type="submit" name="sb" value="Submit" onclick="return validate_upload(this.form)"/>
</div>
```

Using Java and Selenium I've written simple app to send there files:

```
  for (File file : listOfBackupsToSent)
            if (newSftpChrome.getPageSource().contains(file.getName())) {

            } else {
                try {
                    newSftpChrome
                       .findElement(By.name("f"))
                       .sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());

                    newSftpChrome
                       .findElement(By.name("sb"))
                       .click();
                    newSftpChrome
                       .navigate()
                       .toString()
                       .contains(file.getName());
                } catch (TimeoutException tex) {
                    tex.getCause().getCause().printStackTrace();
                    String error_object = tex
                                            .getClass()
                                            .getPackage()
                                            .getName();
                }
            }
     closeChromeSession(newSftpChrome);
    }
```

My problem is that I assume this application send files two times. It opens Chrome, next goes to php interface, fullfills input text bar and click "Submit" (sb) button - and then progress bar "Uploading (xx%)..." goes to 100% two times before file will appear on web page.

Comment: does your javascript method `validate_upload` submit the form?

Comment: @agilob no, this function doesn't submit form. It only checks that Text box is filled.